# Accessing `runtimeconfig.json` content without reading it manually

Tags: c#, .net-core

For certain reasons I need to detect the target .net core version in the executing assembly from a class library. Although this information is available in the `runtimeconfig` file, I don't want to guess the exact file name (as it also includes the name of the executable) and then read and parse it manually because I think the information contained in this file must have been already read and stored in someplace as the compiler already needs to find and target the right assembles in order to execute the app.

The question is that where can I access the content of this file? For example, I used to get the runtime configuration from the `app.config` file using the following method:

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
```

Comment: by open sourcing its products Microsoft also moved its developers to GitHub. You accepted an answer saying that this cannot be done. But if you really want some public API, you should leave feedback to Microsoft directly, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md SO is not suitable for such. If you see my comments in a similar way elsewhere, my opinion remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your assumption is justified. You are correct that the compiler must read this information but it has no reason to store the information, and even if it does, even less reason to think this should be available through an API. (I could be wrong; then again, I won't be convinced until someone shows me such an API.)

If you don't want to guess the name of the file, I think your best bet would be to retrieve a list of all the files in the directory, finding a string that ends with `".runtimeconfig.json"`, and reading that file.

Comment: +1 for the good answer. I was looking for a standard solution that is built-in the framework, but if it does not exists then no other option but to read the file manually.